# How can i use a variable's value for the google map so that it shows the place on map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, yii2

I have a menu in which their are different places on clicking any place a page should open having the details related to the page along with a google map showing the place on the map. but I have created a single page which shows different data for different places on the basis of their `id`. so can any one help me to figure-out how I can use that `id` to show different google map for different places.

Comment: add your current code that you use to configure the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your header...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("AddressView").each(function(){                         
            var embed ="<iframe style='margin-left:10px' width='215' height='215' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'  marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q="+ encodeURIComponent( $(this).text() ) +"&amp;output=embed&iwloc'></iframe>";
               $(this).html(embed);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And put this where you want to display the map within your body...

```
<AddressView>
    <?php echo (preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $POSTCODEVAR)); ?>
</AddressView>
```

Change the style as required.

Comment: I got what i needed after doing some changes. Thanks for the answer @ryan